# Index in query plan is skipped when using OR condition in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, conditional-statements

Say, I have a table `my_table` with field `kind:string` and an index on this field.

I've noticed that Postgres builds two different query plans for the queries:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE kind = 'kind1' OR kind IS NULL;
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE kind = 'kind1';
```

The first one does not use index whereas the second one does. Why?

I know there are a lot of conditions why indexes may be used or not, and I've read a lot about query plans but this case still is not clear to me.

Comment: Actually `kind IN ('kind1', NULL)` is equal to `kind = 'kind1'`.

Comment: @Abelisto, stupid question, edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abelisto explains that the two versions of the query are not the same.  SQL engines (in general) can do a poor job of using indexes for `OR`s.  It is possible that there are so many `NULL` values, that Postgres simply does not think an index is useful when comparing to `NULL`s.  That depends on the data.

You can try rewriting the query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE kind = 'type1'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE kind IS NULL;
```

Postgres might choose to use indexes on each subquery, if they are appropriate for the data.

Comment: Can't rewrite this query like that, it's just a part of a huge one